# Can I ask for a link to survey of methods on specific subject in image processing?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask for a link to survey of methods on specific subject in image processing? Is it considered OK in this site?

The FAQ says that:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

In my humble opinion, it is practical, answerable and based on actual problem. But I want to be extra sure in order not to violate community laws.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, it largely depends on quality of question asked. Usually these things end up downvoted on Stack Exchange because the OP puts very little effort into it. It need not be the case generally. If people are able to guide you to a specific method, they will gladly do it. If people will have to Google for you, that won't work. If the question is very general, try to be maximally specific.

For example, if you ask

> What are different edge detection algorithms and how are they different?

then you're asking someone to write you a book.

If you ask

> What are some good alternatives to the Canny edge detector for images contaminated by Gaussian white noise?

you're providing enough helpful information, and the answers, indeed, will most likely be lists of references and some short descriptions.

Rule of thumb is to ask yourself "would I be compelled to put the effort into answering this question if I knew the answer?".

Answer (score 1):

Asking something here (whether for survey or for discussion) before you have done google search, read some papers or text books - it is definite no no. No site of SO likes this.

Once, you have done some work - you can be specific as well as has good depth. Based on that asking for survey or additional reference is great.

There is one more thing: unlike stack overflow, specialized sites like DSP does have much more research elements; hence providing references both on questions as well as for answers are extremely important.